# Multiple summation inequality

Tags: summation

Is the following inequality true?

$\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{ij}\,a_{ik}\,a_{jl}\,a_{kl} \right) \leq \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}^2 \right)^{1/2}\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty a_{ik}^2 \right)^{1/2}\left( \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{jl}^2 \right)^{1/2}\left( \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{kl}^2 \right)^{1/2}=\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}^2 \right)^2$

where $a_{ij}$s are real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider proving

$$
\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \sum \limits_{j=1}^n \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \sum \limits_{l=1}^n a_{ij}\,a_{ik}\,a_{jl}\,a_{kl} \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \sum \limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \right)^2$$

Let all $a$ be equal, then

$$
\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \sum \limits_{j=1}^n \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \sum \limits_{l=1}^n a^4 \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \sum \limits_{j=1}^n a^2 \right)^2$$
This is 
$$
(a \, n)^8 \leq (a \, n)^4 $$

or 
$$
|a| \, n \leq 1 $$

which won't hold as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: your answer is correct but I made a mistake and there is a typo in typing left hand side of the question. In fact the power (number 2) in the left hand side must be removed. An inequality like Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
\begin{equation*}
\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{ij}\,a_{ik}\,a_{jl}\,a_{kl} \right)^2 \leq 
\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}^2 \right)\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty b_{ij}^2 \right), \quad (1)
\end{equation*}
where $b_{ij}=\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty \,a_{ik}\,a_{jl}\,a_{kl}$. Now again by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{equation*}
b_{ij}^2\leq \left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{kl}^2 \right)\left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{ik}^2 a_{jl}^2\right) \quad (2)
\end{equation*}.
So $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that
$$
\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{ij}\,a_{ik}\,a_{jl}\,a_{kl} \right)^2 \leq 
\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}^2 \right)\left(\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{kl}^2 \right)\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum \limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{l=1}^\infty a_{ik}^2 a_{jl}^2\right)=\left( \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum \limits_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}^2 \right)^4.
$$

Comment: very nice answer!